# How to avoid "Sharing Violation" while getting file path

Tags: c++, filesystems, file-permissions, uac, sharing-violation

I want to retrieve all files/directorys path (nested) in the C:/ drive, at least if they are not currently used or where I have the permission to retrive.

In order to do it recursively, I used
`recursive_directory_iterator`  from `std::filesystem`.

I managed to avoid permission error thanks to `std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied`

However, when my program enter the **C:/drivers**, I get `_Error  _Sharing_violation (32) __std_win_error` because the file it tried to access was probably open.

I have added condition to avoid **C:/Windows** and **C:/drivers** but I want to be sure to avoid the error mentioned previously. Unfortunately, there is no option in filesystem to prevent this error like `skip_permission_denied` for permission, or I don't know it.

Here is my current code :

```
fs::path rootPath = "C:";
fs::path exclPath = rootPath / "\\Windows";
fs::path drivrPath = rootPath / "\\drivers";

const std::filesystem::directory_options options = (std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied);

for (fs::directory_entry p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\", options))
        {
          string filePath = p.path().string();
          // Vérification du type de l'objet
                        
          if (!fs::is_regular_file(p.path()) && filePath.find(drivrPath.string()) == string::npos && filePath.find(exclPath.string()) == string::npos)
                        {


                            cout << filePath << endl;


                        }

        }
```

Don't pay attention to `!fs::is_regular_file(p.path())`, I change it manually to test and retrieve directory or file. I get **sharing violation error** for both.

After some testing I saw that my program fail when checking **C:\DumpStack.log.tmp**. The issue comes from `!fs::is_regular_file(p.path())`. When I removed this verification, the program worked. Now, I don't know how to check object type without triggering **Share Violation**

Comment: I see nothing in this code that should be causing sharing violations, since you are not actually accessing the files themselves, only enumerating filesystem metadata. Which exact line of code is throwing the error? Have you tried simply `catch`ing the error so you can continue the enumeration?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes I don't even open files and I get Sharing Violation. The error comes from filesystem lib. I tried to catch error like in python with try, except, continue but when I get sharing violation the program just stop. I will try to check if the file is open before perform any check from filesystem lib

Comment: but, again, which **specific** statement in your code is throwing the error? What does the call stack look like when the error is thrown? What does your `try/catch` look like that is not working for you? Please [edit] your question with those details.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, I don't know how to check this on VS 2019 but I found where the error comes from. I have edited my question

Comment: I can't imagine what `is_regular_file()` does (why not use `p.is_regular_file()` instead?) that requires accessing the file. But whatever. Have you tried using the overload of `is_regular_file()` that takes a `std::error_code&` parameter? That overload does not throw an exception on failure, it fills the `error_code` with details.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Ohh nice it seems to work now with ```p.is_regular_file()```. I used ```fs::is_regular_file(p.path())``` because I saw in filesystem docs (code exemple)